# Preview Wordpress theme simply by refreshing instead of constantly re-uploading it while developing?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there an alternative to constantly re-uploading the edited version of the theme when developing for WordPress? I have to preview a lot and it's time consuming to keep uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Install a local version of Wordpress, export the live DB and theme and import them to your local machine.  Then make your local changes and push up the new version.

Comment: I'm already working locally. I was asking of how I can make preview changes quicker on while working on localhost.